# to read a double value from file in java

Tags: java

My file contains only 18.746786635311242 as a content and nothing else
when I try to read that double number using code

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("output");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
         f = din.readDouble();
        System.out.println(f);
        din.close();
```

and try to print f the value shows 1.3685694889781536E-71

Answer (score 3):

If it is text, you need to read ti as text, not binary.  The simplest solution is to use a BufferedReader.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output"));
double d = Double.parseDouble(br);
br.close();
```

or use a Scanner.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("output"));
double d = scan.nextDouble();
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The decimals might be overflowing the size of a double on your system or only a certain number of bytes are being read (max that it can read probably 8) and then interpreting that as a double, try using

```
BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(din.readLine());
System.out.println(f);
```

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: double ignores extra digits of precision. The problem is you can't read text as if it were binary.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
Double d = new Double(din.readLine().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `DataInputReader.readLine()` is actually deprecated, I'd do it like this:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("double.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(br.readLine().trim());
System.out.println(f);
br.close();
isr.close();
fin.close();
```

Nonetheless, the key here is to actually use `BigDecimal`.